# Given 2 videos, one edited down and one unedited, how can I automatically find matching sequences between them?

Tags: automation, script

I would like to upgrade some old videos I made long ago using standard definition (or lower) video sources, replacing them with higher definition sources, but without access to the original project files.

For example, it could be a fan-made music video with video sourced from an old film on DVD, but now I have the blu-ray and I want to automatically find and replace all the matched content from the edited video.

To do this I need a library or script for windows that will take two videos, compare one to the other finding all the similarities and reports a list of timecodes where the 2 videos appear to match.

With such a tool I could easily automate this process completely.

I'm sure such a script (open-source) already exists, I just can't find it. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Interesting question. You could try finding matches by audio sync, but that doesn’t usually work well for long content. Maybe break it up into smaller segments first, find where the small clip syncs best to the larger whole, and extend the edit until it doesn’t match. AFAIK, that’s about as automatic as it gets, unless there’s something new out.   Visually, you’d need to index every n frames, come up with a distance metric, then search for nearest neighbors. Point trackers would use a similar algorithm, but they only need to worry about next and previous frame. Following.